# WCF web service is not working with https

Tags: c#, wcf

my web service was working fine on http but on https it is not working.
I think there is some mistake on web.config and I have also changed web.config for https but it was not work for me.

```
<system.serviceModel >
<!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnable ="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>-->
<services>
  <service name="DriverSuvidhaAppService.Driversuvidhaservice" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehave">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="DriverSuvidhaAppService.IDriversuvidhaservice"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>   
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="TcpBindingConfiguration">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehave">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultBodyStyle="Bare" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<!--<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this step-by-step guide from Microsoft to configure your WCF with SSL-

[How to: Configure an IIS-hosted WCF service with SSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl)

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon - consider adding the relevant content since the page linked may disappear and/or the content change (yes, even on MS docs).

Comment: its almost done but when invoking any service from android I'm getting error : HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.